# differences between sentences with 'sorry'

Tags: meaning, grammar

What are the differences between the following sentences with 'sorry':

1. I'm sorry for disturbing you.
2. I'm sorry to disturb you.
3. I'm sorry to have disturbed you.
4. I'm sorry that I disturbed you.
5. I'm sorry that I have disturbed you.

Suppose: I've recently disturbed someone unknowingly, or I've realized that I'm disturbing someone, or I disturbed someone in the past and now realized my mistake. How should I apologize for my mistake? I also want to know which sentence is appropriate in which situation?

Comment: 1 & 2 are appropriate at the *beginning* of knowingly disturbing them, e.g. to ask them a question. 3 is appropriate at the *end* of the same situation. 4 could be used some time *after* the event, e.g. "I'm sorry that I disturbed you earlier.".  5 is similar to 3 and (to me) sounds a little bit over-doing the apologies.

Comment: Just adding to TrevorD's comment. In BrE, #3 can also be the first thing you say when you disturb the person.

Comment: @TrevorD has captured the nuances of this question, 5 is certainly awkward; though without context it is impossible to say if this is from embarrassment or or as he suggests obsequiousness.

Comment: You can use #1 *after* disturbing someone as well.

Comment: @Lawrence Even tho' No. 3 is *past tense*? It doesn't seem quite appropriate if you disturbed them only 1 second previously.

Comment: @TrevorD It's idiomatic. You tap on their shoulder, they turn around, you say, "I'm sorry to have disturbed you, but someone wishes to have a word with you." Linguistically, I suppose *have disturbed* relates to the disturbance in the *recent past*.

Answer (score 1):

**sorry for**

> apology/regret (for both past and immediate actions)

**sorry to**

> regret

it is better to use **sorry to** for immediate actions

in your case,
*sorry for disturbing you* - you are apologizing for what you did a while ago (you can even add an adverb of time eg 'sorry for disturbing you earlier')
but
*sorry to disturb you* - eg you now want to pass some important information to your boss but he is currently busy, you knock on the door and say 'sorry to disturb you but...'
sadness eg 'I'm sorry to hear that you've been ill'

**sorry that**

> regret/sadness

**I'm sorry to have disturbed you**

> use it to end your conversation if you disturbed somebody while they were working.

As to  **I'm sorry that I disturbed you** & **I'm sorry that I have disturbed you**
I've never used this and never heard someone using it.
Sometimes I've used *I'm sorry if I disturbed you* which to me is the same as *I'm sorry to have disturbed you.*

Comment: Why is it "better to use sorry to for immediate actions"?  I have frequently heard & used "I'm sorry that I [have] disturbed you".

Comment: I'm surprized to see that there's the down vote on my question instead of up vote. Is it bad question to ask ? If not, why down vote?